# Android custom table margin

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to use table layout with border in which the table rows are added dynamically. I have made  a shape.xml as following:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#99FFFFFF"
    />
   <corners android:radius="30px"
   />
  <padding android:left="40dp" 
   android:top="0dp" 
   android:bottom="0dp" 
   android:right="10dp"
   /> 
</shape>
```

But my problem is that left margin is not being set.
How to set that?

Answer (score 0):

Margins are only supported by ViewGroup. You shoul set `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute. Find more here:

[ViewGroup margin parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#ViewGroup_MarginLayout)

[ViewGroup_MarginLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#ViewGroup_MarginLayout)